# I have a list [(620.9, 234.5), (591.6, 205.4), (823.4, 205.8)]. After every element i want to insert an element(x,y) after every element

Tags: python, list, insert, append, python-3.7

I want to insert element (x,y) in such a way that the  list [(620.9, 234.5),  (591.6, 205.4),  (823.4, 205.8)] containing x and y cordinates  becomes  [(620.9, 234.5),(621.9, 234.5),  (591.6, 205.4), (592.6, 205.4), (823.4, 205.8),(824.4, 205.8)].

Comment: please make an attempt before asking. Also clarify if you just want to add 1 to the preceding x value for the new point or some other logic

Comment: This is trivially easy to do, so you have to show us what you have tried so we can help you...

Comment: Do you have to modify the existing list or would it be OK to create a new list?

Comment: Hi, i was trying, but could not get proper out. i want to add 1 to the x- cordinate alone. Y remains same and then i have to insert those cordinates after every cordinate.

Comment: i want to create a new list.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a simple for-loop... unless I've misunderstood something?

```
def foo(lst):
    res = []
    for a, b in lst:
        res += [(a, b), (a+1, b)]
    return res
```

you could do it as a list comprehension if you want:

```
sum([[(a, b), (a+1,b)] for a, b in lst], [])
```

and as @cards mentions, there is itertools:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.chain(*[[(a, b), (a+1, b)] for a, b in lst]))
```

I would probably use the first version.

Comment: flat a list with `sum` is not performant. As the documentation recommends, use `itertools.chain` instead

Answer (score 2):

A recursive approach

```
def xshift(coordinates):
    out = []
    if not coordinates:
        return out

    x, y = p = coordinates[0]
    out.extend((p, (x+1, y)))
    out.extend(xshift(coordinates[1:]))
    return out

print(xshift(lst))
```

Comment: I'll give you an upvote for using recursion, even if it makes your non-performant comment a bit ironic :-D

Comment: @thebjorn it was aimed to be a nostalgic solution:)

Answer (score 1):

From what I could understand in your example you want to add an element in your list that is the previous element added whit an offset, here (+1, +0) ?

If so you could do it like

```py
>>> element = (1, 0)
>>> input = [(620.9, 234.5), (591.6, 205.4), (823.4, 205.8)]
>>> output = []
>>> for value in input:
...     output.append(value)
...     output.append((value[0] + element[0], value[1] + element[1]))
...
>>> output
[(620.9, 234.5), (621.9, 234.5), (591.6, 205.4), (592.6, 205.4), (823.4, 205.8), (824.4, 205.8)]
```

But again your original question lacks of explanations

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
lst = [(620.9, 234.5), (591.6, 205.4), (823.4, 205.8)]
new_lst = []

for a in lst:
    new_lst.append(a)
    new_lst.append((a[0]+1,a[1]))

print(new_lst)
```

Another using Numpy

```
import numpy as np
lst = np.array([(620.9, 234.5), (591.6, 205.4), (823.4, 205.8)])

new_lst = []
for a in lst:
    new_lst.extend((tuple(a),tuple(a+[1,0])))


print(new_lst)
```

OUTPUT  `[(620.9, 234.5), (621.9, 234.5), (591.6, 205.4), (592.6, 205.4), (823.4, 205.8), (824.4, 205.8)]`

Another One.

```py
lst = [(620.9, 234.5), (591.6, 205.4), (823.4, 205.8)]
lst = [(a,(a[0]+1,a[1]))for a in lst]
new_lst = []
for a in lst:
    new_lst.extend(a)
print(new_lst)
```

You can also make this in a short way, But I suggested one of the above.

```
lst = [(620.9, 234.5), (591.6, 205.4), (823.4, 205.8)]
new_lst = []
[new_lst.extend((a,(a[0]+1,a[1]))) for a in lst]
print(new_lst)
```